# Using a regex to uncomment a special token (only if it appears inside a /* */ style comment). In perl one-liner

Tags: regex, perl

I am tyring to write a regex for finding a token in a mulit-line c-style comment and removing it from the comment.  For example to do the following transformation:

```
/*
 * comments
SpecialToken
 * commetns
*/
```

->

```
/*
 * comments */
SpecialToken
 /** comments
*/
```

Whenever the above is found within a source file.

I found online (http://ostermiller.org/findcomment.html) a regex for matching /* */ style comments:

```
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

My special token is something like: \nSpecialToken\n, I edited the previous regex to get the following:

```
/\*([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*cloneVerifierMarker_39843829489349873478202370870872077223082([^*]|[\r\n]|(\*+([^*/]|[\r\n])))*\*+/
```

I then made the perl one-liner to remove it from the comment:

```
perl -pi -e 'BEGIN{undef $/;} s/(\/\*(?:[^*]|[\r\n]|(?:\*+(?:[^*\/]|[\r\n])))*)\ncloneVerifierMarker_39843829489349873478202370870872077223082\n((?:[^*]|[\r\n]|(?:\*+(?:[^*\/]|[\r\n])))*\*+\/)/$1\*\/\ncloneVerifierMarker_39843829489349873478202370870872077223082\n\/\*$2/g' temp/file
```

It works in that it removes the token from the comment, but it also seems to pick up cases where the special token is not in a comment.  For example:

The following file has two SpecialToken injected into it, once inside a comment (line 34) and once outside of one (line 2342):

http://pastebin.com/Yq185G8g

After I run the perl one-liner I get the following:

http://pastebin.com/LYftGBX1

The special token is successfully removed from the comment, but the second instance is still dealt with even though it is not in a comment.

I am not sure why this is occurring :(.

The reason I am doing this is I need to keep track of a slice of code across transformations of the source code.  These transformations remove comments so if the special token is injected in a comment I need to remove it from it.

Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Please describe your underlying goal. Is it sufficient to remove all comments, leaving only the tokens?

Comment: RegEx seems like an overkill for this. You could accomplish this by simple parsers.

Comment: This looks like a trivial problem made awkward by confusion of thought. Voting to close

Comment: Goal: I need to mark off a slice of code.  I use a source transformation language to perform some normalizations.  I can't keep track of line numbers across the normalization (they change) so I rely on the markers to allow me to rediscover the slice of interest.  The transformation grammar does not handle comments and instead ignores them.  If my markers end up in a comment they are removed along with it.  I have redefined the java grammar for this langauge to allow the marker to appear between any java token.

Comment: This looks to be a little big for a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for this regex:

```
s/(\/\*)(?:(?!.*?\*\/.*?SpecialToken)(.*?)(SpecialToken)(.*?))(\*\/)/$1$2\*\/$3\/\*$4$5/gs;
```

Test the code [here](http://ideone.com/H5WpQ).